# With Ruby gem aasm, is it possible to define the not(!) operator on guard functions that return a boolean result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aasm

```
class Ticket
  include AASM

  state :new
  state :open
  state :closed

  event :open do
    transitions :from => :new,:to => :closed, :guard => :cancelled?
    transitions :from => :new,:to => :open, :guard => !:cancelled?
  end
  def cancelled?
    true
  end
  def not_cancelled?
    true
  end
end

##Would I need the below?
transitions :from => :new,:to => :open, :guard => :not_cancelled?
```

In an effort to lessen the amount of code I have to write, is it possible to have something like !:cancelled in a guard function?  Or do I have to write a separate not_cancelled? function (as I suspect is the case).

I'm using Ruby 2.1 with gem 'aasm', '~> 3.1.1'

Answer (score 1):

First, `!:cancelled?` expression evaluates to `false` always, so aasm doesn't even call `cancelled?` method in that case. To reduce the amount of code you can have it like the following

```
transitions :from => :new, :to => :closed, :guard => :cancelled?
transitions :from => :new, :to => :open, :guard => Proc.new { |ticket| !ticket.cancelled? }
```

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of AASM you can use the `unless` syntax to avoid defining a separate `not_cancelled` method:

```
transitions from: :new, to: :open, unless: :cancelled?
```